# What is this strange mouse cursor showing in minecraft fullscreen, and how to get rid of it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mouse

Ever since a couple days ago, when I try to play minecraft fullscreen, this strange icon appears in the middle of the screen:

[image]

It captures the mouse events and bumps back to the desktop. Both right and left clicks.

What is it, how can I get rid of it?

No software or mods were installed after Minecraft. Running vanilla 1.8.8

Comment: Have you recently installed any software?

Comment: @Lars no software or mods were installed after minecraft. Running vanilla 1.8.8

Comment: Are there any other people using your computer? They might know what this is

Comment: @Lars nope, single user. Also, I am off the internet on the minecraft PC

Comment: That looks like the icon that comes from using the scroll wheel (or any scroll function) on a mousepad.. :P

Comment: @aytimothy you got it right. Care to post it as an answer?

Comment: Hm.. I don't have credible sources, so I'll wait on that.

Comment: (Unless you can tell me your touchpad's manufacturer and model, I may be able to dig for it)

Comment: @aytimothy yup, outdated drivers once again. I updated my laptop touchpad drivers, and it went off. You should really post your comment as an answer, adding the info from this comment thread.

Comment: @aytimothy "Lenovo Pointing Device" by ELAN *ETD0613

Comment: Maybe you should post it as an answer. Besides: You're **allowed** to answer your own question.

Comment: @aytimothy Nice job not being selfish for rep, I've seen way too many people post comments as answers and want to take the rep...

Answer (score 2):

That pointer is a sideways-scrolling pointer for OPs notebook touch pads, a "Lenovo Pointing Device" by ELAN *ETD0613.

Updating the touchpad driver can solve the issue.

Comment: This is what I was going to suggest. Looks like it could be some kind of accessibility for disabled users as well.